# Splitting LINQ results into array based on column

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am trying to select a few columns from a single row using LINQ to Entities and then split each column into its own point of an array.

I have the LINQ query getting the results I want, but I can't figure out how to split it into the array. I thought using `.ToArray()` would work but it doesn't split them.

```
var LinkData = db.Sections
                 .Where(s => s.ID == SectionID)
                 .Select(s => new
                 {
                    s.Type,
                    s.Route
                 }).ToArray();
```

How can I split the results from the query so I have a single array of two elements: one for Type and one for Route?

Comment: You want a 2-dim array with first value as Type and second value as Route? The question is: why do you need this instead of the array containing the anonymous type created by the `Select`-statement. The latter has the exact same properties.

Comment: @Matthew you mean that `s.Type` to be element 1, `s.Route` element 2 of the array?

Comment: @rbm Yes that is what I am looking for

Comment: @HimBromBeere The "array" I am getting for the query contains one element of the format `Type = DATA, Route = Data`. Which I am not able to split farther down the line.

Comment: So you want an array of arrays?  What are the types of `Type` and `Route`?  Specifically are they the same?

Comment: No I want a single arrary, both columns are strings.

Comment: You are using a anonymous type with "s => new".  Instead specify type like "s => new string[]" or "s => new object[]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Select`-statement already creates a list of two-value-items which are stored in instances of [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb397696.aspx). So there is no need to create a new two-dimensional array for this. Your `linkdata` already contains the data you want, however if you´re after one specific combination of `(Type, Route)` simply call `linkedData[myIndex].Route` or `linkedData[myIndex].Type` respectively.

EDIT: If you really want arrays then the following should work:

```
var arr = linkedData.Select(x => new[] { x.Rote, x.Type }).ToArray();
```

Which will give you an array of arrays where every element itself contains an array of two elements.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I was trying to access it via `LinkeDAta[0]` and `LinkedData[1]` which was braking. I was not aware the query was building it out your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var section = db.Sections
                .Where(s => s.ID == SectionID)
                .Select(s => new
                {
                   s.Type,
                   s.Route
                 })
                .SingleOrDefault();
var LinkData = new [] {section.Type, section.Route};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a List<> instead

Thats what i would do.

Create a public class of Link Data so:

```
public class LinkData
{
    public string type {get; set;}
    public string Route {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your code
create a List of the Link Data:

```
List<LinkData> LinkDataList = new List<LinkData>();
```

then create an object

```
LinkData obj = new LinkData

add stuff to the object 
obj.type = db.Section.Where(s => s.ID==SectionID).Select s=> s.Type new s.Type).SingleOrDefault();
obj.Route = db.Section.Where(s => s.ID==SectionID).Select s=> s.Route new s.Type).SingleOrDefault();;
LinkDataList.Add(obj)
```

This should give you a clear indication of whats what :)